# Facing exception while trying to send email report from Jenkins

Tags: java, email, jenkins, smtp, filenotfoundexception

We are trying to send selenium test reports to developers from jenkins job.We have java code which will parse report xml and send the values in tablular format. But while sending the report we are getting IO exception and the java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\javamail.address.map (The system cannot find the file specified.

```
We tried adding  javax.mail.jar and these files javamail.providers, javamail.address.map, javamail.default.address.map,javamail.default.providers  to JRE Path.But no success
Full logs:
[java] DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
[java] DEBUG: !anyLoaded
[java] DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.address.map
[java] DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\javamail.address.map (The system cannot find the file specified)
[java] sendding messge ---- javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage@1bd4fdd
[java] DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
[java] DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
[java] USER ---> dev@gmail.com, Password ---> test123
[java] DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
[java]
[java] DEBUG: SMTPTransport trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465
[java]
[java] javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
[java] nested exception is:
[java] class javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
[java] nested exception is:
[java] java.io.IOException: Couldn't connect using "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory" socket factory to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[java] at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:218)
[java] at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
[java] at test.email.SeleniumEmailNotification.sendEmail(Unknown Source)
[java] at test.email.SeleniumEmailNotification.runExample(Unknown Source)
[java] at test.email.SeleniumEmailNotification.main(Unknown Source)
[java] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[java] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[java] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[java] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.java:221)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:154)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:832)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:226)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
[java] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[java] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[java] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[java] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:352)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:437)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:458)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1406)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1377)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1261)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:857)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:287)
[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
[java] message sent....
[java] **************************
```

Comment: What's the actual problem: not being able to find the file, or the fact you can't connect to smtp.gmail.com?

Comment: both the things